# List posts that don't have a specific tag?

Tags: php, loop, tags

I am trying to list posts that do NOT have specific tags.

Currently, I am looping through each tag in a post, and if it's doesn't exist, list it.  This works, except that it will list the same URL multiple times, if there are more than one tag.

```
<?php
// the query
$wpb_all_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'post', 'post_status'=>'publish', 'posts_per_page'=>-1)); ?>
<?php if ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
<ul>

    <!-- the loop -->
    <?php while ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) : $wpb_all_query->the_post(); ?>
        <?php $post_tags = get_the_tags(); ?>
        <?php foreach ($post_tags as $tag) : ?>
            <?php if ($tag->name != "Tag1" and $tag->name != "Tag2" and $tag->name != "Tag3"): ?>
                <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
            <?php endif; ?>

       <?php endforeach; ?> 
       <?php endwhile; ?>
    <!-- end of the loop -->

</ul>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

For instance, a post with tags `Fun`, and `Learning` will list twice in a row. I just want this listed once.

Is there a way I can quickly check *all* tags in a post instead of looping?

Edit: I tried adding all the tags to a string, and using `strpos()` but that seems to only check the first condition, and not the second/third:

```
<?php while ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) : $wpb_all_query->the_post(); ?>
   <?php $alltags = ""; ?>
    <?php $post_tags = get_the_tags(); ?>
    <?php foreach ($post_tags as $tag) : ?>
     <?php $alltags .= $tag->name . " "; ?>
     <?php endforeach; ?>
      <?php if ((strpos($alltags, "SCA") == false) and (strpos($alltags, "SCAA") == false) and (strpos($alltags, "Tea and Coffee") == false)): ?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a> - <?php echo $alltags; ?></li>
    <?php endif; ?>
   <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you can filter them out in your original WP_Query using [Taxonomy Parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters). Then you can delete the for loop altogether.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' =>-1,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => array('fun','learning'),
            'operator' => 'NOT IN',
        ),
    ),
);
$wpb_all_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: So this would return the posts that are *not* tagged with "fun" or"learning", right? And would I add `$args` within `array()` or outside it in the `new WP_Query`?

Comment: Yep, exactly. Add the slugs for any terms you want to exclude in the same array as 'fun' and 'learning'. The code I supplied replaces your original Wp_query, I used $args just because it's easier to read.

Comment: Ah! I didn't realize you can add multiple "queries" (?) to that array, my bad.  Thanks for this - I'm not able to test now but when I do, I'll be sure to comment/mark as answer as this looks to be the way to go. Thanks! :D

Comment: Thanks! This works - except it doesn't seem to exclude terms with a space, i.e. `array('fun', 'learning', 'other stuff`)` is not filtering out posts tagged with `other stuff`. (This may be a new question, just mentioning here in case it's a quick fix. Do I need to tag the post with quotes?)

Comment: (Ah, found the answer - the slug for that is `other-stuff`, so I can just use that in the array, not `other stuff`).